# Calculate average array from four given unsigned char arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, average

Suppose I have a toatl of four unsigned char arrays, which are added into a map container like the following:

```
std::map<std::string, unsigned char*> UCArray;
UCArray.insert(std::make_pair("A1", new unsigned char[10000]));
UCArray.insert(std::make_pair("A2", new unsigned char[10000]));
UCArray.insert(std::make_pair("A3", new unsigned char[10000]));
UCArray.insert(std::make_pair("A4", new unsigned char[10000]));
```

I want to get an array filled with average values based on UCArray,  in which all four unsigned char buffers are initialized and populated with valid values. I know that I can carry my point through the use of two "for ... loop". Would please tell if there is any other effective way(s) to do that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `boost::accumulators` and `for_each` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(std::map<std::string, unsigned char*>::const_iterator iter = UCArray.begin();
    iter != UCArray.end(); ++iter)
{
   int nAverage =  std::accumulate(
             iter->second, 
             iter->second+10000, 
             0)  / 10000;
}
```

Comment: That'll calculate the average of A1 only

Comment: @Ajay
Thank you! I want to get an averaged array based on the 4 given arrays. unsigned char* ucAverage = new unsigned char[10000];

Comment: for (int i = 0; < 10000; i++){ unsigned char ucResult = 0; for (int j = 0; j < UCArray.size(); j++) { ucResult = ucResult + unsigned char(UCArray[j][i] / UCArray.size());

Comment: @Armen, That's is implicit. I just gave a simplified example.

Comment: @Ajay, I can't use your example because it can be used to evaluate the average of one array, and the result is the average of the whole array. How could I use std::accumulate to do my above-mentioned job? Thank you.

Comment: @Ajay: Thank you very much! Two questions: (1) What do you make sure the four unsigned char arrays were allocated in consecutive memery like this 0--999 0--999 0--999 0--999? (2) Would you please explain the last statement? Why divided by 10000 not 4?

Comment: Are you new to C++ or STL? You need a foolproof, complete code? Please take the code as sample/reference and derive your own. Nothing personal, don't take my words in wrong sense. 
Just have a variable above loop, add into it, eventually average.

Comment: Arrays will be allocated consecutive by `new`. But for the actual allocation size, you need to keep track of. For that, instead of `unsigned char*`, you may use a `pair` or structure that would hold both size and the pointer.

Comment: Sorry. I thought that your code would be a complete one. I'm not famillar with accumulate function.